# How display the scrolledcomposite content in section in swt formpage

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

Here is my example codes, i had a section in my class called CommentPage extended form the FormPage, i use a scrolledComposite in this section to display some contents,but it does's work, Dose anyone know why?

```
public class CommentPage extends FormPage{
  private FormToolkit toolkit;

  public CommentPage (FormEditor editor, String id, String title) {
    super(editor, id, title);
  }
  @Override
  protected void createFormContent(IManagedForm managedForm) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.createFormContent(managedForm);
    toolkit = managedForm.getToolkit();
    form = managedForm.getForm();
    toolkit.decorateFormHeading(form.getForm());
    form.setText(currVersion.getcName()+currVersion.getvName());
    Composite superContainer = form.getBody();
    superContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,false));
    superContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    createAreas(superContainer);
  }

  private void createAreas(Composite superContainer) {
    Composite left = toolkit.createComposite(superContainer, SWT.NONE);
    Composite right = toolkit.createComposite(superContainer, SWT.NONE);
    GridData leftGrid = new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,true,true);
    left.setLayoutData(leftGrid);
    left.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,true));
    GridData rightGrid = new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,true,true);
    right.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,true,true));
    right.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,true));
    commentArea(right);
  }

  private void commentArea(Composite superContainer) {
    Section section = toolkit.createSection(superContainer, Section.TITLE_BAR|Section.TWISTIE|Section.EXPANDED);
    section.setText("Comment"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    section.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    section.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Composite container = toolkit.createComposite(section, SWT.NONE);
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
    section.setClient(container);

    ScrolledComposite scrollContainer = new ScrolledComposite(container, SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.BORDER);
    scrollContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,true,false));
    scrollContainer.setExpandVertical(true);
    scrollContainer.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
    Color white = Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE);
    scrollContainer.setBackground(white);

    Composite scrollInner = new Composite(scrollContainer, SWT.NONE);
    scrollInner.setBackground(white);
    scrollInner.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));

    Label text = toolkit.createLabel(scrollInner, "test1test2test3");
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData());

    scrollContainer.setContent(scrollInner);
    //scrollContainer.setMinSize(scrollInner.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

  }
}
```

My question:
why the text `"test1test2test3"` for label in `scrolledContainer` in method `commentArea` didnt be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`setExpandHorizontal`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/ScrolledComposite.html#setExpandHorizontal(boolean)) method on the `ScrolledComposite`:

```
ScrolledComposite scrollContainer = new ScrolledComposite(container, SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.BORDER);
scrollContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,true,false));
scrollContainer.setExpandVertical(true);
scrollContainer.setExpandHorizontal(true); // Add this line
```

---

Extracting the just the `ScrolledComposite` piece of your code into something easily testable:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    // Your code below
    final ScrolledComposite scrollContainer = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
    scrollContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
    scrollContainer.setExpandVertical(true);
    scrollContainer.setExpandHorizontal(true); // Added
    scrollContainer.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
    final Color white = Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE);
    scrollContainer.setBackground(white);

    final Composite scrollInner = new Composite(scrollContainer, SWT.NONE);
    scrollInner.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    scrollInner.setBackground(white);
    scrollInner.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    final Label text = new Label(scrollInner, SWT.NONE);
    text.setText("test1test2test3");
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    scrollContainer.setContent(scrollInner);
    // End your code

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: It works, add want ask one more problem, why scrolledComposite does not scroll but the scorlledForm scroll if there are much contents in scrollInner?